# how to send variable along with the redirection in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, api, redirect, node-modules, rest

#Following in my code for redirect along with variable in `nodejs`

```
app.post("/newcall", function(req, res) {
  var f = (req.body.try);
  console.log("val"+ f)
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "www/newcall.html"+f))
});
```

Variable F contain data `hello`

But by doing this I am getting this error in my console

`no such file or directory, stat'c\User\Asus\Desktop\Web\www\newcall\hello`

Can you tell ?what Am I missing In this code??Thanks

Comment: Could you clarify what you're trying to do? The file that you are pointing too doesn't exist on your machine. What do you expect?

Comment: I am trying to send my variable `f` in this `html` file with this code `var f = (req.body.try);
  console.log("val"+ f)
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "www/newcall.html"+f))`

Comment: What I want is Replacement of This code `res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "www/newcall.html"+f))` As I want to send a variable along with it

Comment: So maybe you could try to pass `f` as a query param? Like this: `res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "www/newcall.html") + "?myVar=" + f)`. And then in newcall.html, you need to have some JS that gets the variable `myVar` from the url

Answer (score 0):

Old Issue and GPack answered in comments already that the file in question does not seem to exist (nothing wrong with code above),

however I arrived here due to the title "How to send a variable along with the redirection in node js" and have since discovered the answer to my problem.

If someone ends up here for same reasons as I do then my problem was that I was using

res.redirect instead of res.render("galleryfocus", { image: image });

```
app.post("/galleryfocus", function(req, res) {
  var image = req.body.imageName;
  console.log("image is:", image);

  res.render("galleryfocus", {
    image: image
  });
});
```